# Custom Button URL on Contact Layout

Tags: salesforce-id, custom-button, lookup

I have a custom button on Contact page layout. When a user clicks on the button, it takes the user to Change record type page and sends some other parameters in the URL. They select the new user type and are redirected to the Contact record in Edit mode.

The URL looks like

```
/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?id={!Contact.Id}&con4={!Contact.Current_Employer__c}&CF00Ni0000001a5jC={!User.FirstName}+{!User.LastName}&CF00Ni0000001a5jC_lkid={!$User.Id}&retURL={!Contact.Id}
```

where `&con4` is the ID for Account field. I am sending the value of `Current_Employer__c` on Contact to `Account`field.

The value is being copied to Account field, however once the user clicks save. On save I want the Contact to be linked to the account with name in `Current_Employer__c`.

However, it retains the previous account record.

If they click on the lookup button on Account, while still in edit mode and select Account, they are able to link to different account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]You have the answer right in your URL
as you have `CF00Ni0000001a5jC_lkid and CF00Ni0000001a5jC` one for the userid and one for username, you need to do the same for con4 just populates the name but your con4 param is missing the ID.

try `con4_lkid = {!Contact.Current_Employer__c}` (If current_Employer__C is a lookup it will pick it as ID, if not provide current_employer__c.id).

```
con4={!Contact.Current_Employer__c}&con4_lkid ={!Contact.Current_Employer__c}&
CF00Ni0000001a5jC={!User.FirstName}+{!User.LastName}&CF00Ni0000001a5jC_lkid={!$User.Id}
```

Comment: Unfortunately Current_Employer__c is not a lookup field. It is a text field. Is it possible to clear the previous AccountID form Account field. So that once the click save it look's up using account name now residing in Account field?

Comment: The issue is more similar to giving ur name and not ur boardpass when checking in, the system needs both name and ID. In this context name is ur name, ID is the con4_lkid value. The con4_lkid needs to be provided with the current_employers__C object's ID on save with the name of the object.